# How do I define a layout constraint to keep one label the width of its content and allow another label to fill the remaining space?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Consider the following desired layout. Note that this is not a "layout string" but a proxy for a picture. So | = superview edges, - = space, [xxx] = a view.

|--[label1]--[label2--------------]--[button]--|

The above layout is what I'm trying to achieve. In english:

- `label1` sized to fit content and is padded from the edge of the superview
- `label2` is padded from the edge of `label1` and expands/contracts based on available horizontal space
- `button` is sized to fit content and is padded from the edge of `label2` and the right edge of the superview

I hope this is clear. My current constraint is defined as:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint
 constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[label1]-4-[label2]-4-[button]-8-|"
 options:0
 metrics:nil
 views:views];
```

This results in the following layout:

|--[label1----------------------]--[label2]--[button]--|

**Question**: how can I modify the constraint so `label2` is proportionally sized and `label` and `button` are sized to fit content?

## -- EDIT --

If it helps, here is equivalent code to create the constraints generated by the above sample.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *c1 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:self.label1
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:self
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                          multiplier:1.0f
                          constant:8.0f];

NSLayoutConstraint *c2 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:self.label2
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:self.label1
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                          multiplier:1.0f
                          constant:4.0f];

NSLayoutConstraint *c3 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:self.button
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:self.label2
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                          multiplier:1.0f
                          constant:4.0f];

NSLayoutConstraint *c4 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:self
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:self.button
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                          multiplier:1.0f
                          constant:8.0f];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@ilya's answer is a partial solution. It does keep `label1` from expanding but `label2` can still extend into the area I wanted `button` to be in and `button can be compressed. After some trial and error and reading **all** the docs, I've found a better, and more appropriate solution. Been fun learing auto layout.

Rather than specifying a minimum width for `label1`, which is somewhat artificial and also leaves other problems depending on view content, a better solution is to set the `contentCompressionResistancePriority` and the `contentHuggingPriority` for all views.

The constraints as shown in my question work perfectly as long as I also add the following:

```
    [self.label1
     setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
     forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [self.label1
     setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
     forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [self.label2
     setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
     forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [self.label2
     setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
     forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [self.button
     setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
     forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [self.button
     setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
     forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another constraint for width of `label1` to equal some minimum size (e.g. in the interface builder when you add width constraint it will use current width automatically) but set its priority to be lower.

Comment: thanks, that worked. I discovered another issue perhaps you can answer. If the text in `label2` is too long and needs to be truncated, `button` is being squashed. How can I change the constraints to ensure `button` is always its necessary width and the first view to be squashed is always `label2`. other constraints would need to be adjusted only once `label2` width went to 0.

Comment: never mind, I figured out that I need to use `[button setContentCompressionResistancePriority:forAxis]`

Comment: I've found a better solution that doesn't require setting a minimum width. See my posted answer. thanks for your help in any case.